# How can I capture how long waitFor() waited in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, casperjs, timing

I'm using casperJS to test one application.
Thing is, I want to capture how long it actually took to receive the element I'm waiting for with waitForSelector().

If I set the log level to debug, it shows in the console how long it took for the element I was waiting for to appear:
[image]

I want to get that value and store it in a variable. Is this possible with CasperJS / PhantomJS? If it's not, what framework could I use instead?

Comment: If the given answer solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) it. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The do-it-yourself approach would be to take the time yourself which should be sufficiently accurate:

```
var start;
casper.then(function(){
    start = new Date().getTime();
});
casper.waitFor(...);
casper.then(function(){
    this.echo("waitFor() took " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + " ms");
});
```

Of course this is not very reusable. It would be easier just to register to the [`"log"` event](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#log):

```
casper.on("log", function(logEntry){
    if (logEntry.message.indexOf("waitFor() finished in ") === 0) {
        var time = parseInt(logEntry.message.match(/\d+/)[0]);
        // TODO: do something with the time
    }
});
```

Note that this is asynchronous, but you can still schedule steps (`then*` and `wait*` functions) from the event handler.

If you're also interested in the timeout case, then you can register to the `"waitFor.timeout"` event.